# ReadRegStr fails

Tags: nsis

I am trying to use ReadregStr,

```
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\MyAPP" "ProgramPath"
```

But its returning empty string. When I look in the registry entries under HKLM I could see SOFTWARE\MyAPP.

```
Value Name = ProgramPath
Value Data = C:\MyAPP
```

Where am I doing wrong. Can any one tell me how to get the installed path of "MyAPP"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is 64 bit Windows you need to use `Setregview 64`, if this value is stored in the virtual store you need to read from `HKCU classes\VirtualStore\Machine\Software\...`